# How to manipulate desired arguments to a message handling method in ABAQUS GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, abaqus

We have a button object in ABAQUS-GUI and a corresponding message handler to a particular method. Question: How to pass the desired arguments to that method when calling it as a result of message passing?
For example:
FXMAPFUNC(self, SEL_COMMAND, 30, self.methodName);
FXButton(parent, 'Button Name', None, self, 30);

The main question of mine is, generally speaking, methodName has some input arguments. Where and how are they assigned and passed to the method?